# Retain the System provided Back button Image in Navigation Item

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I am trying to call a function when a bar button item is clicked in the controller but when i set the bar button controller programmatically the system provided image disappears.I want to retain the back button image and add add a functionality when the bar button item is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `UINavigationController` contain `self` in `viewWillDisappear:`

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
         //Back button is clicked  
    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```